# $\sum 0$: does it converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Sometimes I have to do exercise with parameter and, if I substitue particular value of the parameter, I obtain $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0$. But it isn't clear for me if in this case the series converges or diverges.

Comment: Every partial sum is $0$, so the sequence of partial sums converges to $0$.

Comment: by definition, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0=\lim_{k\to \infty }\sum_{n=1}^k0=\lim_{k\to \infty}0=0$

Comment: If this series diverges, then which one can converge ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This series converges to zero. Let $s_k = \sum_{n=1}^{k}0 = 0$, then 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0 = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} s_k = \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} 0 = 0.
$$